# SQLException: Read timed out clientConnectionId

Tags: java, sql-server, sql-server-2008, jdbc

**I encountered following exception when I connect SQL Server database.**

```
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/24 14:03:41 | SEVERE: [EXCEPTION].[com.datasweep.plantops.datamgt.exception.DataMgtException]: PlantOps.DataMgt: [Error initializing site 112 with guid 91799598AD9C4290BB3F5F5EF58D9ABC][Failed to connect: sql:type4:dbmesprod112:dsActive112:deanza:******] CASCADING: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Read timed out ClientConnectionId:f9c1a8c4-326a-4945-a166-e0c906bfe4e5
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/24 14:03:41 | EXCEPTION: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Read timed out ClientConnectionId:f9c1a8c4-326a-4945-a166-e0c906bfe4e5
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/24 14:03:41 |   at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:1667)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/24 14:03:41 |   at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:1654)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/24 14:03:41 |   at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.read(IOBuffer.java:1789)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/24 14:03:41 |   at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.Prelogin(SQLServerConnection.java:1424)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/24 14:03:41 |   at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1319)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/24 14:03:41 |   at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:991)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/24 14:03:41 |   at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:827)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/24 14:03:41 |   at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1012)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/24 14:03:41 |   at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/24 14:03:41 |   at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:207)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/24 14:03:41 |   at com.datasweep.common.db.agent.DBConnectionFactory.open(Unknown Source)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/24 14:03:41 |   at com.datasweep.common.db.agent.DBConnectionFactory.openConnection(Unknown Source)
```

I tried to search the exception from Google, but I have not got any useful message.

So could someone help to me why the exception happened? How to fix the error?

Below is connect code:

```
public static DBConnection openConnection(String dataSourceReferenceName)
    throws Exception
{

    DataSource ds = lookupDataSource(dataSourceReferenceName);
    Connection con = ds.getConnection();
    Object[] serverInfo = getServerInfo(
        dataSourceReferenceName,
        con);
    DBConnection dbConn = new DBConnection(
        con,
        ((Integer) serverInfo[0]).intValue(),
        (String) serverInfo[1]);
    dbConn.setDataSourceJNDIName(dataSourceReferenceName);
    return dbConn;
}
```

Comment: What is your code that establish the connection?

Comment: See above connect code.

Comment: Your code example, don't say to much ... If I'm right youre are dealing with jdni is there all right initialized (user, password, connection string)? I would at first sniff the network traffic - wireshark, tcpdump and stuff. Maybe it shows some reason.